# IF ELSE GOTO not working BAT

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I cant get my if else to work as expected

The code Im ussing is as follows

```
echo %DATE%
set EXPDATE=%DATE:~9,4%%DATE:~6,2%%DATE:~3,2%
IF %EXPDATE% GEQ "20150106" (GOTO EXPIRED) ELSE (GOTO CONTINUE)
exit

:EXPIRED
MSG * update
exit

:CONTINUE
MSG * other code
exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason: You are compariing `20140101` against `"20150106"`. Since at least one side is not a pure-numeric string, a string-comparison is performed. <kbd>"</kbd> is always less than <kbd>2</kbd>

Solution: remove the quotes OR similarly quote the left-hand-side.